# PyInstaller with --noconsole changes scroll bar appearance

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, pyinstaller, ttk

test.py (All it does is show a scroll bar)

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class ScrollTest(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.canvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.create_window((640, 0), window=self.mainframe, anchor=N, tags="self.mainframe")
        self.mainframe.bind("<Configure>", self.configure)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.scroll)
    def configure(self, e):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def scroll(self, e):
        if self.mainframe.winfo_height() > 720:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(e.delta/30), 'units')        
root = Tk()
app = ScrollTest(root)
root.mainloop()
```

With `PyInstaller 3.0`, when I run

```
python pyinstaller.py test.py
```

everything works as expected and the scroll bar appears exactly as expected (i.e. looks like a Windows XP scroll bar).

However, when I run

```
python pyinstaller.py --noconsole test.py
```

the scrollbar has a Windows 10 theme (I am running Windows 10). Why does this happen and how can I have the `XP` theme when using `--noconsole` or the `10` theme when not using it?

Comment: When I do pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole test.py I get the same theme as like using python test.py. Tested with Python 3.5.1 or 2.7.11 and pyinstaller 3.0 on Windows 7. Maybe with Windows 10 this is different.